# MariaDB + php : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 on "LIMIT 1"

Tags: php, mariadb

I was trying to execute an INSERT query which ensures that only 1 row is inserted and avoid duplicate insertions/
here is my SQL string that i used inside my PHP file:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `users`( `user_name`,`email`,  `password`, `active`) VALUES (:name, :email, :pass, :active) LIMIT 1";
```

I got this following error:

```
Calling BeforeException -> string(211) "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 1' at line 1"
```

i think MariaDB Insert command do not use LIMIT syntax. 
please suggest.Thanks

Comment: Your correct - INSERT doesn't need LIMIT, after all there is only 1 row to insert.  Duplicates is another thing which you can update with https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/insert-on-duplicate-key-update/

Comment: Thanks @NigelRen. As i mentioned, i also  want to avoid duplicate insertions. Is there anything else to add on query to do so? or current on is enough? Thanks again

Comment: Just remove `LIMIT 1`